# Startup Disk Almost Full

Tags: macos, mac, ssd

My mac is running out of space, but I do not know why.
It says that I have only about 100-200MB free space when I go to Apple icon > About this mac > Storage.
But when I check how much storage is taking when I enter my Macintosh HD it is only 87GB out of my 121GB SSD.
Even calculating through apps like disk space pro shows the same number (87) and not almost 121GB!

Where should I find the files that take so much space?

Comment: Have you emptied your trash?

Answer (score 2):

My application of choice for this is [Disk Inventory X](http://www.derlien.com/). It's very simple to use and has helped me find large files, or clusters of small cache files extremely fast.

Some of the missing space could be system files, or space reserved by the SSD for overhead protection.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you rebooted?

There's an old Unix trick of deleting an open file to hide it. Its blocks don't become free space until the file is closed, even if there's no longer a filename entry in any directory pointing at that file. Rebooting would clear that up.

Have you run a Disk Utility "Repair" of your volume?

Corrupted volume data structures could cause discrepancies like this. Repairing your volume from Disk Utility should clear up that kind of thing.

Comment: There is more space after reboot, but as soon as I start going through my notes from school and use safari the space is taken so quickly. Another thing is that it says, that I have about 60GB of apps on my mac, but my Application folder only weighs about 25-30. There is no way that I have double this amount.